# BDC Recording with Mandatory Fields

Tags: ui-automation, abap, sap-basis

Is there any way where we can know all the mandatory fields within a transaction say MK01 for SHDB Recording for BDC Prog ?

Answer (score 0):

No, because fields can be switched to mandatory/optional or even invisible at runtime depending on arbitrary parameters. You will be able to identify certain fields that are mandatory unconditionally, but it is not generally possible to identify all mandatory fields beforehand.